# TensorRT WARNING: Convolution + generic activation fusion is disable due to incompatible driver or nvrtc

Tags: tensorrt

I got this warning when create `Engine` from ONNX model with `TensorRT`:

`[TensorRT] WARNING: Convolution + generic activation fusion is disable due to incompatible driver or nvrtc`

`[TensorRT] WARNING: Detected invalid timing cache, setup a local cache instead`

Does it affect my final output `Engine`? (Still got `<class 'tensorrt.tensorrt.ICudaEngine'>`)

I'm using onnx 1.9.0, CUDA 11.1 and TensorRT 8.0.

Thanks!